# How to flip a text that fits a curve horizontally and verticaly in php?

Tags: php, flip

I have some text that fits a curve, but the text is flipped. I can't flip it as an image because it is made to fit a curve.

I have to do that because I need to generate an image with some text in a circle, and the text should face me.

This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: How are you generating the image in the first place ? Show us the code you have.

Comment: @chip calculate the position and angle of every character and place them using imagettftext().